# How to output PDF by HTML with CSS in Laravel project

Tags: laravel

I am looking for a way to create PDF from (BLADE )HTML with CSS

I am using this.

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.7",
```

but its output looks misconversion.

```
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('test'
        )->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');
        return $pdf->stream("aaa.pdf");
```

I use this html

https://github.com/okoppe8/PaperFormToHTML

result here.

[image]

Comment: can you show your html

Answer (score 1):

Use Custom font to display.So download `simhei.ttf` from any source.and place it `public` folder.Then you can use below css

```
<style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: SimHei;
            src: url('simhei.ttf') format('truetype');
        }

        * {
            font-family: SimHei;
        }
    </style>
```

As per github issue
Ref:https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/198

Download font from
https://www.wfonts.com/font/simhei